# Does return-path or reply-to affect email deliverability?

Tags: email

I want to send an email that looks like:

```
Sender: user@A.com
From: xyz@B.com
Reply-To: aaa@C.com
Return-Path: aaa@C.com
```

A.com is owned by me, and B.com and C.com are owned by a client. I am mostly concerned that email clients will flag this email as spam since the reply-to and return-path are from another domain than the sender. Is this a valid fear?

Answer (score 4):

I have experienced that setting the `Reply-To` header does degrade deliverability, in two ways:

- [MailChannels](http://mailchannels.com/) (a SMTP sending service that we use) will funnel messages with a `Reply-To` through their "junk pool" of IP addresses, almost all of which are on some blacklist (usually at least UCEPROTECT1).
- SpamAssassin's `FREEMAIL_REPLYTO*` rules trigger if `Reply-To` contains a freemail address (gmail, yahoo, hotmail, et al) which doesn't match the `From` header (which is often true in this use case, since the `From` header can't be set arbitrarily because of [SPF](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework).

**If these guys are suspicious of `Reply-To`, perhaps others are too?**

Since we depend on these systems, and want good deliverability, we must use these from headers:

```
Envelope-From: no-reply@website.com
From: no-reply@website.com
```

(Where the domain `website.com` has SPF configured to allow mail sent from the web server and/or SMTP gateway IP addresses. `no-reply` is used because the "sender" is *Website Visitor*, and there is no valid address we can use here – it would be silly to allow replies to go to `info@website.com`.)

This is unfortunate, because the convenience of being able to use email for CRM and easily *Reply* to the person behind the email is gone. I can't think of a better solution. I have solicited MailChannels to change their policy for sending `Reply-To`emails through junk IP addresses, to no effect.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen any that would hold it against you. A quick check of a few spam scanners indicates that if it's even noticed, it must not be a large factor in their spaminess decision.

If you have all your other ducks in a row (SPF or SenderID, DKIM, and DNS) the rest of the message body/headers have significantly less impact on the spaminess score of the message.